# A question about the structure of the part in bold in this sentence

Tags: syntax

Below is a sentence from an article on New York Times.

> A week before Michael T. Flynn resigned as national security adviser, a sealed proposal was hand-delivered to his office, **outlining a way for President Trump to lift sanctions against Russia**.

I would like to ask about the structure of the bold part and what it is modifying in the sentence.

I can't understand the exact meaning of the part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *A week before Michael T. Flynn resigned as national security adviser,
>   a sealed proposal was hand-delivered to his office, **outlining a way
>   for President Trump to lift sanctions against Russia***.

The constituent in bold is a gerund-participial clause modifying the noun phrase “a sealed proposal”. Semantically, it is similar to the relative clause in *… a sealed proposal was hand-delivered to his office, **which outlined a way for President Trump to lift sanctions against Russia.***

Answer (score 2):

Reworded this way, it should be more clear.

> a sealed proposal outlining a way for President Trump to lift sanctions against Russia was hand-delivered to his office.

The proposal outlines a way to lift sanctions.
The proposal was hand-delivered to his office.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very neat and clear so I could undertand this problem perfectly!